# SQL Update Parent Table Field based on Multiple Child Table Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have the following sample table structures for a `parent` / `child` relationship.

`parent` table

```
id    LongText
--------------
10    
20
```

`child` table

```
id    char     value
--------------------
10    COLOR    RED
10    HEIGHT   1FT
20    COLOR    BLUE
20    WIDTH    2FT
```

I have a requirement that specifies that certain fields from the child table rows need to be concatenated together and placed in the parent table. I would like to complete this in a single SQL query *if possible*. The update statement that I have written is as follows.

```
UPDATE
  parent
SET
  LongText = COALESCE(LongText, N'')
              + child.char + N': ' + child.val + ','
FROM
  parent INNER JOIN child
    ON
      parent.id = child.id
```

But I only get the following results.

```
id    LongText
------------------
10    COLOR: RED,
20    COLOR: BLUE,
```

I would expect (or I should say I *WANT*) to get this.

```
id    LongText
------------------
10    COLOR: RED,HEIGHT: 1FT
20    COLOR: BLUE,WIDTH: 2FT
```

Is this possible? Any suggestions as to how I can do this? Any help is appreciated!

Here is a [SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7e108/4) for reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
update parent
set longtext =
    stuff((
    select ',' + c.char + ': ' + c.val
    from child c
    where c.uid = parent.uid
    for xml path(''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'');
```

I have updated your [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7e108/16/1) with the solution.

1. [STUFF()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) function to remove the leading `','` (comma) from the first characteristic.
2. [FOR XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx) to create an XML document from a query result.  This is a well known trick with SQL Server - because the column is not named, there is no element produced and only the raw text (of each row) is output, mashed together into a single row.

Very few articles on the internet attempt to explain it in detail, since the code is pretty much left as an explanation in and of itself.