# SQL Update Parent Table Field based on Multiple Child Table Rows with Length Requirement from Each Child Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have the following sample table structures for a `parent` / `child` relationship.

`parent` table

```
id    ShortText
--------------
10    
20
```

`child` table

```
id    char     value    order
-----------------------------
10    COLOR    RED      1
10    HEIGHT   1FT      2
10    LENGTH   10FT     5
20    COLOR    BLUE     1
20    WEIGHT   100LBS   3
20    WIDTH    2FT      4
```

I have a requirement that specifies that certain fields from the child table rows need to be concatenated together and placed in the parent table `ShortText` field. The `ShortText` field can be a maximum of 10 characters.

I would expect (or I should say I *WANT*) to get this.

```
id    ShortText
---------------
10    RED,1FT,
20    BLUE,2FT,
```

I would like to complete this in a single SQL query *if possible*. Any suggestions as to how I can do this and avoid iterating through each child record set? Any help is appreciated!

---

Here's what I have tried so far.

The following update statement...

```
UPDATE
  parent
SET
  ShortText = COALESCE(ShortText, N'') + 
           CASE WHEN DATALENGTH(COALESCE(ShortText, N'') + child.val + ',')/2 < 10
                THEN COALESCE(ShortText, N'') + child.val + ',' ELSE N'' END
FROM
  parent INNER JOIN child
    ON
      parent.id = child.id
```

But I only get the following results.

```
id    ShortText
------------------
10    RED,
20    BLUE,
```

---

I also tried the following and was unsuccessful because the case statement that is checking the length is not executed on each child table row, only on the before ShortText.

```
UPDATE
    p
SET
    p.ShortText = p.ShortText +
        STUFF((
        SELECT
            CASE WHEN 
                    DATALENGTH(p.ShortText)/2 + DATALENGTH(c.val + N',')/2 < 10
                THEN
                    c.val + N','
                ELSE
                    N''
                END
        FROM
            child as c
        WHERE
            c.id = p.id
        FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('.','NVARCHAR(max)'), 1, 0, N'')
FROM
    parent as p
```

Here is a [SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57242/7) for reference. I also posted and got an answer for a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351679/sql-update-parent-table-field-based-on-multiple-child-table-rows), but this is a different requirement and I can not scale it for the length requirement. As always, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check p.ShortText on NULL and then update derived table

```
UPDATE x
SET x.ShortText = NewShortText
FROM (SELECT p.ShortText, STUFF((SELECT CASE WHEN 
                          DATALENGTH(ISNULL(p.ShortText, ''))/2 +  DATALENGTH(ISNULL(c.value, '') + N',')/2 < 10
                                             THEN c.value + N','
                                             ELSE N'' END
FROM child as c
WHERE c.id = p.id
FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('.','NVARCHAR(max)'), 1, 0, N'') AS NewShortText 
FROM parent as p) x
```

**UPDATE 14.11.2012**

```
;WITH cte (id, uid, val)
AS
 (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.[uid] ORDER BY c.val DESC),
         p.uid, c.val
  FROM parent p INNER JOIN child c ON p.uid = c.uid
  ), cte2 (id, uid, val)
AS
 (  
  SELECT id, uid, val
  FROM cte
  WHERE id = 1 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.id, c.uid, CAST(ISNULL(ct.val, '') + ', ' + ISNULL(c.val, '') AS nvarchar(100)) AS val
  FROM cte c JOIN cte2 ct ON c.id = ct.id + 1 AND c.uid = ct.uid
)
UPDATE x
SET x.ShortText = x.MaxNewShortText
FROM
 (
  SELECT p.uid, p.ShortText, CASE WHEN DATALENGTH(val)/2 < 10
                                  THEN val END AS NewShortText,
  MAX(CASE WHEN DATALENGTH(val)/2 < 10
           THEN val END)
  OVER(PARTITION BY p.[uid]) AS MaxNewShortText
  FROM parent p JOIN cte2 ct ON p.uid = ct.uid
  ) x
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57242/148/0)

Comment: I updated my [SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57242/38) with the query that you suggested and I received the same results that I got with the second update statement that I tried (the one with the `STUFF` command). Any idea why the `CASE` is not checking the  `DATALENGTH` before concatenating it?

Comment: @JoeFletch Because DATALENGTH(p.ShortText)/2 + DATALENGTH(c.val + N',')/2 for all records < 10

Comment: I see now. So `DATALENGTH(ISNULL(p.ShortText, ''))/2 +  DATALENGTH(ISNULL(c.value, '') + N',')/2 < 10` is only checking the current child record AND the `p.ShortText` *before* the update of `p.ShortText` is completed. I want the update to `p.ShortText` to run/concatenate on each child record and dynamically check before each row is appended.

Comment: I still question if this is even possible. I know that I can do this with a variable; `SELECT @ShortText = @ShortText + CASE WHEN DATALENGTH(@ShortText + N',' + c.val)/2 < 10 THEN @ShortText + N',' + c.val ELSE N'' END FROM ...` But I would have to iterate over the `parent` records in order to do this with a variable and I would think that there would be a big performance hit.

Comment: @JoeFletch Look at my update answer. I not absolutely uderstand your val order, but we almost at the purpose))

Comment: Sorry I should have explain the `order` field better. It determines the order (priority) at which the `child` records should be added to the `ShortText` field. With `id` 10, the `child` records are `RED,` `1FT,` `10FT,`. `RED,` gets added since the `ShortText` is less than 10. Then `1FT,` gets added since the concatenated description `RED,1FT,` is less than 10. Then the next `child` record, `10FT,` gets skipped since `RED,1FT,10FT,` is greater than 10 characters.

Comment: I updated my [SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57242/72) with your most recent edit, but unfortunately, it did not work. I'll keep trying. Let me know if you have any more ideas. Thanks!

Comment: @JoeFletch Try now .I updating on my answer.

Comment: Looks good to me! Now all I have to do is understand all of the statements so that I can apply it elsewhere! Thanks for all of your efforts here!